# Unable to install Matlab 2008

Tags: installation, matlab

I am unable to install Matlab 2008 in ubuntu. I am getting the following error when I have typed `./install` in terminal window.

```
bash: ./install: Permission denied
```

and when I typed `sudo ./install` I am getting the error as

```
sudo: ./install: command not found
```

Please assist me in installing Matlab 2008.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should execute the command `./install` in the directory, where the install-script is.
2. Maybe the install-script isn't marked as executable.
   This can be done with: 
   `chmod a+x install` (also in the directory where install is located)